Identify Legacy Sites and Web Parts using PnP
In light of Microsoft disabling support for custom scripts and attempting to move everyone from classic pages to modern pages. How can someone search through their SP sites to find sites that are at risk of breaking once these changes publish sometime in November?

You can identify if site is having classic experience team site or modern sites from their web templates.
